# PrimeFaces fileUpload and input binding

Tags: jsf, data-binding, file-upload, primefaces

I'm using `<p:fileUpload mode="advanced"`> and it works fine with file uploading. The problem is when `fileUploadListener` method in the backing is called no other input element in the form is bound to the backing bean. It seems that PF `fileUpload` is not a normal JSF component, as it doesn't either fire [validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865136/primefaces-3-4-fileupload-validator-not-fired). Any idea how to have form submitted before `fileUploadListener` is called?

Comment: Ever find an answer?  I am having the same experience

Comment: I found now answer, as it seems to be a bug. The workaround I used was to put an onblur ajax event on each input in the page to be submitted to the backing bean as soon as it loses its focus.