# p:fileUpload required="true" and custom validator doesn't work

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Since the `required` attribute of `<p:fileUpload>` still doesn't seem to work in PrimeFaces 4.0 final, I have tried to create a custom validator as follows.

```
@FacesValidator(value="fileUploadValidator")
public final class FileUploadValidator implements Validator
{
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) 
    throws ValidatorException
    {
        System.out.println("fileUploadValidator called.");

        if(!(o instanceof UploadedFile))
        {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            message.setSummary("Error");
            message.setDetail("Required");
            throw new ValidatorException(message);      
        }
    }
}
```

And specified with `<p:fileUpload>`.

```
<p:fileUpload mode="advanced" 
              required="true"
              multiple="true"
              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
              fileUploadListener="#{bean.fileUploadListener}">
    <f:validator validatorId="fileUploadValidator"/>
</p:fileUpload>
```

But the validate method was never invoked. Since I'm displaying images in `<p:dataGrid>`,  this validation is highly required. Is there a way to validate an empty `<p:fileUpload>`?

Comment: I didn't look in 4.0 source code yet, but the following answer for 3.4 may hold true for 4.0 as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865136/primefaces-3-4-fileupload-validator-not-fired/13868094#13868094

Comment: @BalusC : Is there any workaround to this? This can of course be checked in the respective JSF managed bean to see, if the `UploadedFile` object is `null` or not but doing so causes some JSF/PrimeFaces components like `<p:dataTable>` to be update unnecessarily which in turn, causes some costly queries to be fired upon the database which is plain wrong and clumsy.

Comment: Theoretically, a custom renderer should do. Can't tell from top of head without checking the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@ManagedBean(name = "docBean")
@ViewScoped
public class DocumentBean implements Serializable
{
  private UploadedFile file;

  public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event)
  {
     uploadedFile = event.getFile();
   }

   //action
   public void viewImage()
  {
    if(uploadFile==null){
     FacesContext saveContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     saveContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Error", "Upload file  required"));
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: This can be done in a managed bean for sure but it is not a validator after all which is invoked and performs its job far before any associated properties/fields in a managed bean is populated.