# p:fileUpload required='true' not working

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{expeditionGroupView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"
                      update="upload-messages" sizeLimit="10000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" 
                      cancelLabel="#{lbl['label.cancel']}" uploadLabel="#{lbl['label.send']}" label="#{lbl['label.choose.file']}"
                      invalidFileMessage="#{msg['error.invalid.file.type']}" required="true"/>
```

I am trying to use required="true" to validate  my p:FileUpload, why it does not work?

Comment: I don't see a hibernate validator... Please read [ask], [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: No validator is supposed to work with `<p:fileUpload>`. You need to perform validation yourself manually in a managed bean. Several questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19925708/1391249) are in pending.