# FileUpload required="true" doesn't work in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to put validation in my `<p:fileUpload>` . when the user upload without putting any file he get's an error message. I'm using `mode="simple"` and `required="true"` but `required="true"` doesn't work.

P.S: I need to use `mode="simple"` because I need `<p:commandButton>` to submit other data.

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel id="image" value="Select Image: *" />

    <p:fileUpload value="#{Jcalendar.file}" mode="simple"
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                  required="true"
                  requiredMessage="File not selected !!"/>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="Submit"
                         ajax="false"
                         action="#{Jcalendar.Upload}"
                         update=":form:msgs" />
    </f:facet>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: No validators including your own custom validators can work with `<p:fileUpload>`.

Comment: @Tiny can you show me how ? i'm new to  primefaces

Comment: Nothing other than putting the validation logic into the listener (or sonewhere maybe) of `<f:fileUpload>` can be done (unless some tedious hacks / home-grown rederers are made). [See for example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13865136/1391249) (and [maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22659268/1391249)).

Comment: Forgot to consider that you are using `mode="simple"`. You may have chances to implement a custom validator (I never used `mode="simple"`).

Comment: @Tiny they all use mode="advanced"  but i can not use it because I don't want to use (FileUploadEvent event)

Comment: Since I have not yet used `mode="simple"`, I can only hope that a custom validator should work for you using `mode="simple"` (using `mode="advanced"`, it does not work. The `validate()` will not be invoked). Try implementing it and see, if the `validate()` method is invoked or not. If it does then, you can put any logic of your interest in that method afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

As per the 5.2 source code, this will indeed fail when Servlet 3.0 native upload is being used instead of Apache Commons FileUpload.

The [`NativeFileUploadDecoder#decodeSimple()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.2.RC3/org/primefaces/component/fileupload/NativeFileUploadDecoder.java#NativeFileUploadDecoder.decodeSimple%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%2Corg.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) will only set the submitted value to an empty string when the input was not submitted at all. This will thus fail if the input is actually submitted, but with an empty value.

```
51        if(part != null) {
52            fileUpload.setTransient(true);
53            fileUpload.setSubmittedValue(new NativeUploadedFile(part));
54        }
55        else {
56            fileUpload.setSubmittedValue("");
57        }
```

The [`CommonsFileUploadDecoder#decodeSimple()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.2.RC3/org/primefaces/component/fileupload/CommonsFileUploadDecoder.java#CommonsFileUploadDecoder.decodeSimple%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%2Corg.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload%2Corg.primefaces.webapp.MultipartRequest%29) will set the submitted value to an empty string when the submitted file name is empty, exactly as intented.

```
54        if(file != null) {
55            if(file.getName().equals("")) {
56                fileUpload.setSubmittedValue("");
57            } else {
58                fileUpload.setTransient(true);
59                fileUpload.setSubmittedValue(new DefaultUploadedFile(file));
60            }
61        }
```

Your best bet to get it to work is to report an issue to PrimeFaces guys and in the meanwhile either customize/patch the renderer, or switch back to Commons uploader.