# How to filter mime type of an upload file

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In our project I need to make a server side validation of an uploaded file (e.g. to prevent the upload of a "fake" file with an allowed extension). On the client side I've already done it using **allowTypes** param of **p:fileUpload** but i need this additional further control.

I've already tried by extending Primefaces' **FileUploadFilter** but I'm still not able to access the actual file uploaded from **MultipartRequest**: I can only access all the form fields instead.

```java
Enumeration params = multipartRequest.getParameterNames();
```

I can probably access the file via reflection but I don't think it's a safe and "right" thing to do.
The best option to me is to override ***FileUploadRenderer*** but it's seem a bit too much just to add an additional check all over my application.

We are using Primefaces 3.5, but we're okay to upgrade to a newer version if this featuer is available in newer ones.

Any idea on what can/should I do to make this control happens ?

edit: I can add a `FileUploadListener` to all my controllers that manage views in which there's a `p:fileUpload`but I was wondering if there's a way to intercept ALL the Multipart request and validate my item in there.

Comment: Are you using the simple or advanced uploader mode? Did you try to simply use a validator? I don't think overriding PF classes or reflection is necessary here.

Comment: I'm using the advanced mode. Using a validator could be handy but in that way I need to change all my p:fileUpload and it. I thought it could be possible to intercept all the multipart request and put my validation there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating dimensions of an uploaded image in file upload listener in PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659268/validating-dimensions-of-an-uploaded-image-in-file-upload-listener-in-primefaces)

Comment: In PrimeFaces 7.0 this is built into the FileUpload using validateContentType="true" see bullet #3 https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/fileupload?id=more-secure-file-upload  it requires Apache Tika on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In your backing bean, you can take care for validation like this

```
            long size = uploadedFile.getSize();

            String content = uploadedFile.getContentType();

            InputStream stream = uploadedFile.getInputStream();

            byte[] contentBytes = new byte[(int) size];
            stream.read(contentBytes);
            String base64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(contentBytes);
            if(content .... is not)
```